# How to convert large number strings into integer in c++?

Tags: c++, string, integer, long-integer

Suppose, I have a long string number input in `c++`. and we have to do numeric operations on it. We need to convert this into the `integer` or any possible way to do operations, what are those?

```
string s="12131313123123213213123213213211312321321321312321213123213213";
```

Comment: Given that such a number cannot fit "regular" integral types, you have to either reimplement the operations you need yourself, or use a bignum library.

Answer (score 2):

Your best best would be to use a large numbers computational library.

One of the best out there is the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/manual/)

Example of a useful function to solve your problem::

`Function: int mpz_set_str (mpz_t rop, const char *str, int base)`

> Set the value of rop from str, a null-terminated C string in base
>   base. White space is allowed in the string, and is simply ignored.
>
> The base may vary from 2 to 62, or if base is 0, then the leading
>   characters are used: 0x and 0X for hexadecimal, 0b and 0B for binary,
>   0 for octal, or decimal otherwise.
>
> For bases up to 36, case is ignored; upper-case and lower-case letters
>   have the same value. For bases 37 to 62, upper-case letter represent
>   the usual 10..35 while lower-case letter represent 36..61.
>
> This function returns 0 if the entire string is a valid number in base
>   base. Otherwise it returns -1.

Documentation: https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the numbers you want to handle are way to big for any standard integer type, so just "converting" it won't give you a lot. You have two options:

1. **(Highly recommended!)** Use a *big integer* library like e.g. [`gmp`](https://gmplib.org/). Such libraries typically also provide functions for parsing and formatting the big numbers.
2. Implement your big numbers yourself, you could e.g. use an *array of `uintmax_t`* to store them. You will have to implement all sorts of arithmetics you'd possibly need yourself, and this isn't exactly an easy task. For parsing the number, you can use a *reversed [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble)* implementation. As an example, here's some code I wrote a while ago in C, you can probably use it *as-is*, but you need to provide some helper functions and you might want to rewrite it using C++ facilities like `std::string` and replacing the `struct` used here with a `std::vector` -- it's just here to document the concept

   ```
   typedef struct hugeint
   {
       size_t s;       // number of used elements in array e
       size_t n;       // number of total elements in array e
       uintmax_t e[];
   } hugeint;

   hugeint *hugeint_parse(const char *str)
   {
       char *buf;

       // allocate and initialize:
       hugeint *result = hugeint_create();

       // this is just a helper function copying all numeric characters
       // to a freshly allocated buffer:
       size_t bcdsize = copyNum(&buf, str);

       if (!bcdsize) return result;

       size_t scanstart = 0;
       size_t n = 0;
       size_t i;
       uintmax_t mask = 1;

       for (i = 0; i < bcdsize; ++i) buf[i] -= '0';

       while (scanstart < bcdsize)
       {
           if (buf[bcdsize - 1] & 1) result->e[n] |= mask;
           mask <<= 1;
           if (!mask)
           {
               mask = 1;
               // this function increases the storage size of the flexible array member:
               if (++n == result->n) result = hugeint_scale(result, result->n + 1);
           }
           for (i = bcdsize - 1; i > scanstart; --i)
           {
               buf[i] >>= 1;
               if (buf[i-1] & 1) buf[i] |= 8;
           }
           buf[scanstart] >>= 1;
           while (scanstart < bcdsize && !buf[scanstart]) ++scanstart;
           for (i = scanstart; i < bcdsize; ++i)
           {
               if (buf[i] > 7) buf[i] -= 3;
           }
       }

       free(buf);
       return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If string contains number which is less than `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`, then `std::stoull()` is the best opinion.

```
unsigned long long = std::stoull(s);
```

`C++11` and later.